# Strange Error when trying to save Plotly figure to image file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, visualization, r-plotly

I have a script which creates a plotly chloropleth, shaded world map. I've been using it following an example to create a custom shaded world map, and all has been working fine, except every time I attempt to save the figure directly using the following plotly methods I get the following error, and I have no idea why:

> ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.choropleth.ColorBar: 'autotick..

It's essential for the purpose of what I'm doing that I can save the created figure directly through the programme, rather than open it up through a HTML link (which works fine, and doesnt give the mentioned errors). I have tried both the lines:

```
pio.write_image(fig, 'fig1.png')     #import plotly.io as pio
```

and

```
plotly.offline.iplot(fig,validate=False, filename ='worldmap', image ='png')
```

but both seem to return the same error so I'm clueless? any help or even alternative methods would be massively appreciated. Here is the full code, with part commented out for functional purposes:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.io as pio
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

 df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv')

'''
df=df.set_index('COUNTRY')
for x, y in zip(Countries, country_counts):
    df.loc[x, df.columns.get_loc('GDP (BILLIONS)')] = y
df[0].replace({None: 0}, inplace=True)
df['GDP (BILLIONS)']=df[0]
print(df)
'''

data = [dict(
    type='choropleth',
    locations=df['CODE'],
    z=df['GDP (BILLIONS)'],
    text=df.index,
    colorscale=[[0, "rgb(5, 10, 172)"], [0.35, "rgb(40, 60, 190)"], [0.5, "rgb(70, 100, 245)"],\
                [0.6, "rgb(90, 120, 245)"], [0.7, "rgb(106, 137, 247)"], [1, "rgb(220, 220, 220)"]],
    autocolorscale=False,
    reversescale=True,
    marker=dict(
        line=dict(
            color='rgb(180,180,180)',
            width=0.5
        )),
    colorbar=dict(
        autotick=False,
        tickprefix='',
        title='Leads'),
)]

layout = dict(
    title='',
    geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False,
        projection=dict(
            type='Mercator'
        )
    )
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
pio.write_image(fig, 'fig1.png')
#plotly.offline.iplot(fig,validate=False, filename ='worldmap', image ='png')

#plot(fig, validate=False, filename='world-map', image='png')
```

Comment: Why did you tag your post with `r-plotly'?

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate issues here.  The ValueError on colorbar requires removing

```
autotick=False, 
tickprefix='',
```

In order to not save the file but to display it interactively, change

```
plotly.offline.iplot(fig,validate=False, filename ='worldmap', image ='png')
```

to

```
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

Including the filename property forces a file save.